# type A satisfying requirements of type B

Tags: go

I have a question about a data type/structure being able to satisfy the requirements of another type that's expected in a function call.

In [feed.go](https://github.com/jteeuwen/go-pkg-rss/blob/master/feed.go) of an RSS and Atom feed handler written in Go, there is a `New` helper function that takes a ChannelHandlerFunc as a third argument, which you can see gets passed as a parameter to a `NewDatabaseChannelHandler`, which returns a DatabaseHandler, as you can see below. A DatabaseHandler has a ChannelHandler embedded in it. You can see in the `New` function that the return value  of NewDatabaseChannelHandler (i.e. the DatabaseHandler) gets passed as the 3rd parameter to `NewWithHandlers`. However, `NewWithHandlers` as you can see, requires a ChannelHandler as the third parameter.

Question: Why doesn't `NewWithHandlers` throw an error when it's passed the `DatabaseHandler` as a return value from `NewDatabaseChannelHandler` as a third parameter. `NewWithHandlers` expects a ChannelHandler not a DatabaseHandler?

```
func New(cachetimeout int, enforcecachelimit bool, ch ChannelHandlerFunc, ih ItemHandlerFunc) *Feed {
    db := NewDatabase()
    f := NewWithHandlers(cachetimeout, enforcecachelimit, NewDatabaseChannelHandler(db, ch), NewDatabaseItemHandler(db, ih))
    f.database = db
    return f
}
```

then NewWithHandlers accepts a ChannelHandler as a third argument

```
// NewWithHandler creates a new feed with handlers
// People should use this approach from now on
func NewWithHandlers(cachetimeout int, enforcecachelimit bool, ch ChannelHandler, ih ItemHandler) *Feed {
    v := new(Feed)
    v.CacheTimeout = cachetimeout
    v.EnforceCacheLimit = enforcecachelimit
    v.Type = "none"
    v.channelHandler = ch
    v.itemHandler = ih
    return v
}
```

This [file](https://github.com/jteeuwen/go-pkg-rss/blob/master/databaseHandler.go) is the source code for the NewDatabaseChannelHandler

However, NewDatabaseChannelHandler doesn't return a ChannelHandler, it returns a DatabaseHandler

```
func NewDatabaseChannelHandler(db *database, chanhandler ChannelHandler) ChannelHandler {
    database := new(databaseHandler)
    database.db = db
    database.chanhandler = chanhandler
    return database
}

type databaseHandler struct {
    db          *database
    itemhandler ItemHandler
    chanhandler ChannelHandler
}
```

Comment: interfaces are a key concept in Go. Make sure you get a good grasp on these before you go much further [spec#Interface_types](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types), [Effective Go #Interfaces](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interfaces)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DatabaseHandler` satisfies the `ChannelHandler` interface with this method:

```
func (d *databaseHandler) ProcessChannels(f *Feed, ch []*Channel)
```

The interface requires:

```
type ChannelHandler interface {
    ProcessChannels(f *Feed, newchannels []*Channel)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so even though the DatabaseHandler has fields that the ChannelHandler doesn't, the mere fact that it satisfies the interface by implementing that method means it can be passed? The fact that DatabaseHandler had so many other fields confused me I guess

Comment: Yes. In fact the majority of types that implement the basic interfaces like `fmt.Stringer`, or `io.Writer` have other methods not covered by those interfaces.